# Can't receive mail others than my own

Tags: smtp, imap, postfix-mta, dovecot

I am currently trying to configure my first Postfix - Dovecot - PostgreSQL installation.

When I connect from **Thunderbird**, I can receive and send mail on my 3 domains with virtual and real mail accounts. Emails are instantaneously sent.

It works too when I use **mail** *(mailutils)*. But emails need like 1 minute to be sent.

**telnet** 25 from the server and outside the server send mail correctly too. Emails are instantaneously sent.

However, when I try to send mail from my **Gmail** or **Yahoo** mail accounts to this domain, I receive this kind of error :

Gmail

```
Technical details of temporary failure:
The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. Learn more at http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=7720
[(10) mail.domain-1.com. [MY_IP]:25: Connection timed out]
```

And I don't get any message in /var/log when sending a mail from external domains

Software versions :

- LinuxMint  : 16 Petra (Debian Wheezy)
- Postfix    : 2.10.2
- Dovecot    : 2.1.7
- PostgreSQL : 9.1.13

Here is my main.cf :

```
debug_peer_list                 = domain-1.com
smtpd_banner                    = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff                            = no
append_dot_mydomain             = no
readme_directory                = no
transport_maps                  = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/transport.cf
virtual_uid_maps                = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/uids.cf
virtual_gid_maps                = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/gids.cf
virtual_alias_maps              = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/virtual.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps            = pgsql:/etc/postfix/sql/mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base            = /var/spool/virtual_mailboxes/
virtual_mailbox_limit           = 51200000
mydestination                   = domain-1.fr domain-2.com domain-3.org localhost.$mydomain localhost
smtpd_recipient_restrictions    = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable          = yes
smtpd_sasl_type                 = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path                 = private/auth
queue_directory                 = /var/spool/postfix
```

Here is my master.cf :

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
```

There is currently no security like SSL or anti-spam. I just put an SHA512-CRYPT password.

As for my DNS configuration (it must come from here, ... but I don't see anything) :

```
domain-1.com.       10800   IN  MX      10   mail.domain-1.com.
mail.domain-1.com.  10800   IN  CNAME        www.domain-1.com.
www.domain-1.com.   300     IN  A            SERVER_IP
```

Answer (score 1):

I had just put a firewall only allowing mails from me.

Allowing anywhere on port 25 and 143 just made it...

...

Comment: how you did it ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: @sonubreeze : I added it in AWS configuration. If you use a software firewall, you may configure it there. If you're behind a physical one you'l have to perform it there.